# Showing a alert dialog from the any screen of the android phone

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

While pressing the power button we are able to see a alert dialog in any android device from any activity. Just like that i want to show a alert dialogue when my application receives a broadcast intent. How i can implement that function ?

Comment: post the code that have done in broadcast class

Comment: The dialog that you are talking about is only available in the system code.  Apps do not have access to it.  The best you can do is popup a dialog in resonse to a broadcast intent.  But, it's scope is still limited to your application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this intent to your Activity Manifest tag.
2. In your Activity's `onCreate()`, Handle the intent you received:

   - If it matches your intent, show the dialog.
   - Else, do nothing.

Comment: my question is not related to broadcast intent. See the alert dialogue  when you are pressing the power button. That alert dialogue you can get from any activity. Example message app, browser app, homescreen, launcher screen etc. Like that i want to show alert dialogue after receiving a broadcast intent.

Comment: When you press the power button your phone gets locked. I don't know what you mean!

Answer (score 0):

As the previous person stated, you cannot have this functionality, since it is in the Android Framework code, unless you edit that code to expose it.  An example of the functionality you are looking for (from Android code) resides in the PowerUI class, which extends SystemUI.  In SystemUI, there is a Context(mContext) that sub-classes use to show Alerts on any screen. This is what you need.  I had to recently do this for an app.  I just mirrored what PowerUI did, and created another child of SystemUI. The PowerUI does this to let you know that your battery is low(from any activity/screen), among other things.

It's a bit of a bear, but that is what I believe you are talking about. Doesn't really help you much though, if you are releasing to the public.  But, for a personal app...